# nestjs, GRPC server and micro services architecture

Tags: node.js, microservices, grpc, nestjs

I've started a new project with nestjs with microservices, but it's my first microservices project and i don't' have enough knowledge. 
During my documentation study, I can't find a way to use a microservice with grpc and HTTP at the same time.

In my architecture, I have got a few microservices that have to serve REST API for the client but have also to serve grpc request for "internal" purpose, is that a right decision?

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct to say "*I can't find a way to use a microservice with grpc and HTTP at the same time*" since GRPC uses HTTP. GRPC is not a protocol, it is a way to serialize messages, by exposing HTTP endpoints you have the possibility to choose between different alternatives such as XML; REST/JSON or GRPC.

Normally following the "hexagonal architecture" philosophy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) you should be able to separate the logic from the adapters and your project can implement multiple adapters for the same logic, for example one adapter in HTTP/REST and another in HTTP/GRPC. On the other hand, a way to avoid having to implement multiple ports is to always choose HTTP/GRPC and use Envoy as a proxy between HTTP/REST and HTTP/GRPC (see https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/web/) but final solution depends on many factors